# element[class="name"] instead of .class

Tags: css, responsive-design

I wonder why `element[class="name"]` seems to used primarily in responsive emails instead of the usual `.class`?

Also, unless I'm missing something, if an element has multiple classes for eg.

`<span class="class1 class2"></span>` then neither of these appear to work:

```
element[class="class1"] { }
element[class="class2"] { }
```

.. why is that?

Comment: *"seems to used primarily in responsive emails"* - What is the source for this conclusion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> element[class="name"]

This is attribute equals selector and it will select the element with exact value. When you have multiple classes the exact match is not there and it does not select. Using attribute contains selector or other wild card selector would get the element. Following contains selector would get elements that have `class1` as attribute class's value. It will get element with class name class123 as well.

```
element[class*="class1"]
```

> I wonder why element[class="name"] seems to used primarily in
>   responsive emails instead of the usual .class?

This [article](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/2011/04/media-query-issues-in-yahoo-mail-mobile-email/) probably talks about this.

Attribute selectors are being used to avoid an unusual glitch in
Yahoo! Mail, [reference](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/dev-resources/guides/mobile/)

> It turns out that Yahoo! Mail ignores any styles that use attribute
>   selectors, meaning that you can use these in your @media queries to
>   ensure that Yahoo! Mail doesn’t override existing inline styles with
>   your @media -defined ones. Read more over [here](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/2011/04/media-query-issues-in-yahoo-mail-mobile-email/).

Comment: Thanks! Can you please also answer why responsive email templates use the attribute equals selector instead of the usual `.class`?